# TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker, cdn

I am not able to access daterange picker. When i am clicking it nothing is happening. in the console it is showing that TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function.
I have same code used on other page, which is working fine.

[image]

This is code in my head section.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>ui/css/custom.css">


<script>
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);
    
});
</script>
```

And this is code in my php file.

```
<div id="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
<span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this code without the jQuery OnLoad iffy.

```
var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
var end = moment();

function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
}

$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
}, cb);

cb(start, end);
```

Comment: Now, there is no error in console, but, if I am trying to click on datepicker nothing is happening.

Comment: paste this code in the console window and then try again.

Comment: I am trying to work it out similar in power bi custom visuals. It still gives me same error. TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_124__(...).daterangepicker is not a function

Comment: @user3095179 you added required libraries in there?
jQuery, daterangepicker.js

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem package.json has this format. "@types/daterangepicker": "^2.1.17", "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41", "daterangepicker": "^3.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",    ... Any idea if something is wrong here. I also installed moment latest version. Still it gives me same error.

Comment: @AakashKumar these are types for daterangepicker, not libraries you need to add libraries, can you share that part of package.json file?

Comment: @MuhammadZubairSaleem I think I mentioned "datarangepicker: 3.0.5. For a detailed view, I mentioned something over here: Please have a look https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker/issues/1950

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? I do not see any final solution here. Removing the JQuery OnLoad does not change the error.

Answer (score 13):

You are including jQuery twice. Once on line 2 and again on line 5. Try removing one of them, but make sure you are including it above Bootstrap.

Alternatively, if you need both you can look into using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: Removing the first one will break bootstrap,  unless you reorder the includes.

Comment: I removed this... <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SalmanKhan - Does this work for you? https://codepen.io/seanvm/pen/PewrmZ

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js" defer></script>
```

- Just add **defer** to this particular script and it will work properly

Screenshot of it

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

In my case (on laravel mix) its due "defer" on app.js.
So the solution is add defer for moment and daterangepicker.js.
For more details how defer work refer to this
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-defer

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i missed to include the moment.js

Answer (score 0):

For me it was having 2 different versions of jQuery installed in react app.

Verified by checking the lock file (package-lock/yarn.lock).
I had specified the version to install in the package.json.

So I ended up having the specified version + one that brings the latest jQuery from another package's dependencies.